# Using pointers and structs in functions

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, user-defined-functions

I've just started looking into C++, and I'm can't seem to wrap my head around a couple of concepts.

#### Context

Struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int left;
    int right;
    int mid;
} boundtype;
```

Function:

```
boundtype sortintarray(int *curArray[], boundtype bounds){
    int left(bounds.left);
    int right(bounds.right);
    unsigned int refValue(*curArray[(left+right)/2]);

    while (left < right){
        if (*curArray[left] > refValue){
            if (*curArray[right] < refValue){
                int swap(*curArray[left]);
                *curArray[left] = *curArray[right];
                *curArray[right] = left;
                right--;
                left++;
            } else{right--;}
        } else{left++;}
    }
    bounds.left = left;
    bounds.right = right;
    bounds.mid = (left + right)/2;

    return bounds;
};
```

Function Call:

```
unsigned int pancakes[10]; //Filled via std::cin
int size(sizeof(pancakes)/sizeof(int));
boundtype bounds(0,size - 1);
bounds = sortintarray(&pancakes, bounds);
```

#### My Questions

#### 1)

When I define a struct, is it possible to do something like:

```
typedef struct{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c = a/b;
}
```

and expect c to be constantly updated whenever a and b are updated?

#### 2)

Is my way of passing in a struct/ returning a struct/ defining the function as so correct?

#### 3)

I understand that `*` references the value of an address, whereas `&` references the address of a value. I'm confused about how I use them in functions. How do I pass in the value, how do I define it in the function input, and how do I reference the value within the function?

My whole goal with this particular example is to edit the original array without making copies in the function.

#### Any advice/help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Whole lot of questions you have!

Comment: You can drop the typedef when defining a struct (and union. Classes weren't a "problem" in C anyway). Just put the identifier after the struct keyword.

Comment: Can't make sense of this questions. Really!

Comment: `(1)` isn't possible. For initializing members you need to have  a compile time constant.

Comment: thokra Drop the typedef? Would that work in C as well?
g-makulik What parts are confusing? How can i improve my questions?
UchiaItachi I see. So i would have to recalculate and update by myself everytime?

Comment: @sihrc: I'm not that much of a C-guy. I know you don't need it in C++ though. ;) I tend to consult a standard in such cases: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Comment: @thokra Wow! That's quite the packet. Thanks for the link!

Comment: It's a standard! duh! ;) Welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No. But your code is C not C++. The C++ way to do what you want is

```
struct boundtype
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int get_c() const { return a/b; }
};
```

2) Yes

3) To sort the array in place you only need a pointer

```
boundtype sortintarray(int *curArray, boundtype bounds){
    int left(bounds.left);
    int right(bounds.right);
    unsigned int refValue(curArray[(left+right)/2]);

    while (left < right){
        if (curArray[left] > refValue){
            if (curArray[right] < refValue){
```

etc.

A pointer to the first element of an array is sufficient to access the whole array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So, `boundtype function_name(boundtype boundname){return boundname;);` is correct?

Comment: So to pass in the array, I would just use `sortintarray(&pancakes, bounds)`?

Comment: @sihrc Yes it's correct. structs can be passed to and returned from functions.

Comment: @sihrc No `sortintarray(pancakes, bounds);` No need for `&`, the name of an array is converted to a pointer to it's first element.

Comment: I see. Is it possible to use (&pancakes) even though it may be inefficient? Like, in the function throw a * in every reference. and pass in define it as `sortintarray(int curArray)`

Comment: If you do that you will likely get warnings from your compiler because the types are wrong. The type of `&pancakes` it not convertible to `int*`, but this is ok, `&pancakes[0]`

Comment: hmm I see, then would you ever pass in an address to access the value?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36565/discussion-between-john-and-sihrc)